# Facebook SDK cURL 7.34.0 fails, 7.19.7 works

Tags: php, facebook, api, curl, libcurl

I got a strange problem here at our CentOS 6.4 box (2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.i686) running PHP 5.5.8. 
All Facebook apps stopped working since we upgaded cURL / libcurl to version 7.34. It just times out when trying to execute ´curl_exec($ch)´.

Using yum downgrade and yum install curl libcurl, I was able to reproduce the error (and always works), see the differences of phpinfo() here:

[image: cURL comparison]

Tried to run curl in verbose mode and catch the data sent and recieved.

If someone other wants to know how to catch this cURL data (wasn't to easy to find):

```
$opts[CURLOPT_VERBOSE] = true; // enable verbose logging
$verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');
$opts[CURLOPT_STDERR] = $verbose;
curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
rewind($verbose);
$verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);
echo "Verbose information:\n<pre>". htmlspecialchars($verboseLog), "</pre>\n";
```

This works with 7.19.7:

```
* About to connect() to graph.facebook.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 173.252.101.48... * connected
* Connected to graph.facebook.com (173.252.101.48) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=*.facebook.com,O="Facebook, Inc.",L=Palo Alto,ST=California,C=US
*   start date: Oct 28 00:00:00 2013 GMT
*   expire date: Aug 05 23:59:59 2015 GMT
*   common name: *.facebook.com
*   issuer: CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3,OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10,OU=VeriSign Trust Network,O="VeriSign, Inc.",C=US
> POST /me HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: facebook-php-3.2
Host: graph.facebook.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 232
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< ETag: "a4238b670d50df51506644bd20277a7cffbfaa80"
< Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
< Last-Modified: 2014-01-15T13:20:35+0000
< Pragma: no-cache
< X-FB-Rev: 1097933
< X-FB-Debug: ekyERaUVGaiB7H+tLQn1m6sll33KkF8CUhlHGd9/lGs=
< Date: Tue, 28 Jan 2014 09:51:40 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 253
< 
* Connection #0 to host graph.facebook.com left intact
```

When trying to do the same with 7.34.0, httpd runs with 100% and gets a timeout after 30 seconds (or whatever is set in php.ini). No verbose output at all, just times out. Nothing to find in Apache error_log.

Any ideas how to debug any further?

Regards, 
Max

Answer (score 0):

Its very hard to tell you without being on your position. But still here are few suggestion from my end. Not sure how much it will help you.

First write a basic curl code and run it for the site example.com(for example). And see what does it return.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

If above code doesn't work for you, then its the issue of curl.

Now, run the same code by changing the url into https://www.google.com/ and also adding the other curl options for ssl/certificate things(use from your existing code). And check what it does. If it doesn't work, then its the issue of ssl with curl.

If it works then change the url into your graph api url. And check what it does. If it doesn't then its the problem of `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` for curl that you are using.

Finally, you can also try to run my above code with the below option for both https://www.google.com and https://graph.facebook... sites. And see how they react.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```